# How to handle provisioned throughput exception dynamodb query_2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

Using the example from the docs:

```
>>> rev_with_d = users.query_2(
...     account_type__eq='standard_user',
...     last_name__beginswith='D',
...     reverse=True,
...     limit=2
... )

>>> for user in rev_with_d:
...     print user['first_name']
'John'
'Jane'
```

How would throughput exception be handled in this case?

I have tried using exponential backoff inside the for each loop, but the exception does not get caught there.

Edit:

Traceback by request:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kgraph.py", line 51, in <module>
    for user in rev_with_d:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/results.py", line 62, in __next__
    self.fetch_more()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/results.py", line 146, in fetch_more
    results = self.the_callable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/table.py", line 1132, in _query
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 1522, in query
    body=json.dumps(params))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 2100, in make_request
    retry_handler=self._retry_handler)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 937, in _mexe
    status = retry_handler(response, i, next_sleep)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/dynamodb2/layer1.py", line 2134, in _retry_handler
    response.status, response.reason, data)
boto.dynamodb2.exceptions.ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: 400 Bad Request
{u'message': u'The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API', u'__type': u'com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#ProvisionedThroughputExceededException'}
```

Comment: Do you have a backtrace you can provide or are you asking for the hypothetical situation? Also, boto already has an exponential backoff built in. Simply set the DynamoDBConnection.NumberRetries attribute to set it to whatever you want, default is 10.

Comment: Yeah, by the time boto raises that error, it already tried to run your query quite a few times.

Answer (score 2):

I think you better set `max_page_size` parameter of `query_2`. 
you should set a value that is based upon your table's Read Throughput and item size.